# How to upload file using Cakephp 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create a file upload on cakephp, I haven't been able to find any decent tutorials for cakephp 3.0 that go in detail, and I don't understand how to install plugins.

I have this in my add section

```
echo $this->Form->create('filename', array('action' => 'upload', 'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('filename');
```

I haven't added anything in the controller yet

```
/**
 * Index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Courses']
    ];
    $this->set('contents', $this->paginate($this->Contents));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['contents']);
}

/**
 * View method
 *
 * @param string|null $id Content id.
 * @return void
 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function view($id = null)
{
    $content = $this->Contents->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Courses']
    ]);
    $this->set('content', $content);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['content']);
}

/**
 * Add method
 *
 * @return void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
 */
public function add()
{
    $content = $this->Contents->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $content = $this->Contents->patchEntity($content, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Contents->save($content)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The content has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The content could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $courses = $this->Contents->Courses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('content', 'courses'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['content']);
}

/**
 * Edit method
 *
 * @param string|null $id Content id.
 * @return void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $content = $this->Contents->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $content = $this->Contents->patchEntity($content, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Contents->save($content)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The content has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The content could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $courses = $this->Contents->Courses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('content', 'courses'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['content']);
}

/**
 * Delete method
 *
 * @param string|null $id Content id.
 * @return void Redirects to index.
 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $content = $this->Contents->get($id);
    if ($this->Contents->delete($content)) {
        $this->Flash->success('The content has been deleted.');
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error('The content could not be deleted. Please, try again.');
    }
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

but after this no idea what to do.

Comment: If you don't understand plugins educate yourself http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html or hire somebody to teach you. The manual really covers everything that is part of the framework, so just use it.

Comment: Can you post the code from the controller so we can see what's happening there.  I am assuming you have a submit button or some mechanism to submit the file to the controller.

Comment: You can’t have looked for very long. The CakePHP Cookbook has a section on handing uploaded files: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-file-inputs

Comment: that link above for helpers is what I already have, I  was more looking for the controller part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to decide on WHEN you're going to handle uploads. I've managed to create a dirty (but working) approach using beforeMarshal method and afterSave method (I'll explain why these two at the end).

If you create your file input like:

```
<?= $this->Form->file('submittedfile', ['class' => 'form-control input-upload', 'style' => 'height:100px']) ?>
```

or for hasMany association:

```
<?= $this->Form->file('images.'.$i.'.submittedfile', ['class' => 'form-control input-upload', 'style' => 'height:100px']) ?>
```

and you define the right associations:

```
$this->hasMany('Images', [
            'foreignKey' => 'model_id'
        ]);
```

you could process those files before the Entity gets patched and saved:

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options) {
        $images = array();
        $dir = md5(time().$data['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['images']); $i++) {
            $image = $data['images'][$i]['submittedfile'];
            if (!empty($image['name'])) {
                if(!isset($data['id'])) {
                    $data['temp_dir'] = $dir;
                }
                else {
                    $dir = $data['id'];
                }
                if ($this->Images->uploadFile(array('img', 'model', $dir), $image) === true) {
                    $images[] = array('name' => pathinfo($image['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME), 'ext' => pathinfo($image['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                }
            }
        }
        $data['images'] = $images;
    }
```

This is of course an example. I've decided to check, if there's an ID property set on the Entity (like for edit), because if it's not (like for create), you have to somehow identify the right path.

Here you've got a file uploading function:

```
public function uploadDir($path = array()) {
        return $this->wwwRoot . implode(DS, $path);
    }

    public function uploadFile($path = array(), $filetoupload = null) {
        if (!$filetoupload) {
            return false;
        }
        $dir = new Folder($this->uploadDir($path), true, 755);
        $tmp_file = new File($filetoupload['tmp_name']);
        if (!$tmp_file->exists()) {
            return false;
        }
        $file = new File($dir->path . DS . $filetoupload['name']);
        if (!$tmp_file->copy($dir->pwd() . DS . $filetoupload['name'])) {
            return false;
        }
        $file->close();
        $tmp_file->delete();
        return true;
    }
```

If you added your images while there was no subdirectory with main entity ID, you have to rename the directory as soon as you get the ID:

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, \ArrayObject $options) {
        if(!empty($entity->temp_dir)) {
            $this->Images->renameFolder(array('img', 'model', $entity->temp_dir),$entity->id);
        }
    }
```

calling:

```
public function renameFolder($path = array(), $newName) {
        $oldPath = $this->wwwRoot . implode(DS, $path);
        $nameToChange = array_pop($path);
        array_push($path, $newName);
        $newPath = $this->wwwRoot . implode(DS, $path);
        return rename($oldPath, $newPath);
    }
```

1. Using beforeMarshal you're able to inject your file data into Entity structure before the whole Entity is ready for saving (with associations).
2. Using afterSave you're able to identify the main object ID and call the set of objects you've uploaded before.
3. Remember to set recursive rights for saving files onto the directory, as well as rights for creating and renaming directories.